# XSD to XML conversion not contain all the fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xsd

I have a XSD file and when i try to conver this file using following code

```
   public XmlDocument GetXml(XmlDocument xsd, XmlQualifiedName rootElem)
      {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd.OuterXml),new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit
        });

        XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
        var generator = new XmlSampleGenerator(schema, rootElem);
        generator.MaxThreshold = 1;

        var xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlStringBuilder);
        generator.WriteXml(writer);

        var resultXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        resultXmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStringBuilder.ToString());
        BlankOutValues(resultXmlDoc.DocumentElement);
        return resultXmlDoc;
    }
```

under the applicant i am setting a node employeetype like

but while converting all the field which is not contain all the values

while converting this with online tool it is working fine any idea?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E33YO.png)

under the node Time At Employer we have 2 fields but in other end it looks like an attribute!

Comment: <xs:element name="PreviousEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>

Comment: is it possible to add custom type like
<xs:element name="PrimaryEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>
       <xs:element name="SecondEmployment" type="EmploymentType1"/>
       <xs:element name="ProtectedEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>
       <xs:element name="PreviousEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>

Comment: Most likely the online tool is converting everything to text while your code is looking for the correct types.  Do you really need the schema?  It probably is easier to just read the xml in to the c# code.  Post sample of the xml if you want additional help.

Comment: @jdweng This is the details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168306/issue-while-converting-xsd-with-complextype-to-xml-using-msdn-microsoft-xml-xmlg