# Issue while converting XSD with complextype to XML using MSDN Microsoft.Xml.XMLGen( XmlSampleGenerator API)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I am trying to convert an XSD with complex type into XML
I could not getting the expected result.
The xsd is shown below.

But only one of the node showing correct data
but the second one not showing the correct result
attaching the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SoD0.png)
any idea on this??
I can able to convert it through online, at that time it is working fine
Do we have any limitation in samplegenerator to use same complex type in multiplenode?

Here is the XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="XXX">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Applicant">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="PrimaryEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>
                        <xs:element name="SecondEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="EmploymentType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TimeAtEmployer">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence> 
                    <xs:element name="Years" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="Months" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Expected xml file

```
<Applicant>
<PrimaryEmployment>
  <TimeAtEmployer>
    <Years>123</Years>
    <Months>123</Months>
  </TimeAtEmployer>
</PrimaryEmployment>
<SecondEmployment>
  <TimeAtEmployer>
    <Years>123</Years>
    <Months>123</Months>
  </TimeAtEmployer>
</SecondEmployment>
```

Current XML

```
`<Applicant>
        <PrimaryEmployment>
          <TimeAtEmployer>
            <Years>123</Years>
            <Months>123</Months>
          </TimeAtEmployer>
        </PrimaryEmployment>
        <SecondEmployment>
          <TimeAtEmployer>      
          </TimeAtEmployer>
        </SecondEmployment>
      </Applicant>`
```

Sample code that i have tried

```
XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("po.xml", null);
        textWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        XmlQualifiedName qname = new XmlQualifiedName("Loancontract", "http://tempuri.org");
        XmlSampleGenerator generator = new XmlSampleGenerator("sample.xsd", qname);
        generator.WriteXml(textWriter);
```

Example2

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xml;
            var rootElement = new XmlQualifiedName("sampledata");
            var XSD = @"<xs:schema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" elementFormDefault=""qualified"" attributeFormDefault=""unqualified""> 
                <xs:element name = ""SampleData2"">

                <xs:complexType>

                <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name = ""Applicant"">

                <xs:complexType>

                <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name = ""PrimaryEmployment"" type = ""EmploymentType""/>

                <xs:element name = ""SecondEmployment"" type = ""EmploymentType""/>

                </xs:sequence>

                </xs:complexType>

                </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>

                </xs:complexType>

                </xs:element>

                <xs:complexType name = ""EmploymentType"">

                <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name = ""TimeAtEmployer"">

                <xs:complexType>

                <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name = ""Years"" type = ""xs:int""/>

                <xs:element name = ""Months"" type = ""xs:int""/>

                </xs:sequence>

                </xs:complexType>

                </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                </xs:schema>
                ";
            XmlElement serializedElement = Serialize(XSD);
        }
        public static XmlDocument GetXml(string xsd, XmlQualifiedName rootElem)
        {
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd), new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit
            });

            XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
            var generator = new XmlSampleGenerator(schema, rootElem);
            generator.MaxThreshold = 2;

            var xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlStringBuilder);
            generator.WriteXml(writer);

            var resultXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            resultXmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStringBuilder.ToString());
            //BlankOutValues(resultXmlDoc.DocumentElement);
            return resultXmlDoc;
        }
        public static XmlElement Serialize(object transformObject)
        {
            XmlElement serializedElement = null;

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(transformObject.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, transformObject);
            memStream.Position = 0;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(memStream);
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd().Replace("utf-8", "utf-16")), new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit
            });
            XmlDocument xsd = new XmlDocument();
            var rootElement = new XmlQualifiedName("LoanContract");
            xsd = GetXml(transformObject.ToString(), rootElement);
            return serializedElement;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have analysed this and when I googled i saw like a piece of code like </xs:complexType>

Comment: Please post text of schema.

Comment: Is this the same question as the one you asked earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165908/xsd-to-xml-conversion-not-contain-all-the-fields. You can edit your existing question to improve it.

Comment: I need to see actual XML file with data.  Is it possible the XML does  not have years for secondary employment.  The schema look correct.  The secondary employment may not be set to an array.

Comment: I have added 2 screenshot

Comment: <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:element name="XXX">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>        
    <xs:element name="Applicant">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>       
       <xs:element name="PrimaryEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>
       <xs:element name="SecondEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>       
      </xs:sequence>

Comment: <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>            
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 <xs:complexType name="EmploymentType">
  <xs:sequence>   
   <xs:element name="TimeAtEmployer">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>

Comment: <xs:element name="Years" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="Months" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>   
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType> 
</xs:schema>

Comment: Sure!
do we have solution or idea for this?

Comment: OK, now we can see the XSD. Now what is your problem with it? It seems that you are creating something out of it which does not work as expected. You need to show us what you did and what you expect.

Comment: In my XSD I have added one complextype (<xs:complexType name="EmploymentType">) and I have mapped the same under 2 node
(<xs:element name="PrimaryEmployment" type="EmploymentType"/>
 <xs:element name="SecondEmployment" type="EmploymentType" />)
Under the complextype  I have added one node (TimeAtEmployer)and 2 child node under it(Years and months). So while generating the xml i need to get That two child nodes under the 2 element,but  one of the node looks like an attribute
I have added the output screenshot in the question @KlausGütter

Comment: I don't get your problem. It seems you are generating some sample XML, i.e. an XML file with invented data and the only restriction that it satisfies the schema (it would have been good if you posted the XML file instead of the image). Note that the child elements of an <xs:sequence> may occur any number of times, including 0. This is probably what you are experiencing.

Comment: What I want to do is have a complex type so that I can re-use the EmploymentType throughout the code. The problem I am having is that within the XML it is not reusing it.
only top of the node uses the complextype and showing node but the second one ie; SecondEmployment in xsd not reusing the complextype.

Comment: Why don't you post an XML file that shows what you want?

Comment: Added the current xml and expected XML file in the question @KlausGütter

Comment: As I said, also the "current XML" is totally valid according to the XSD. If you want to enforce Years/Months to be present, add a `minOccurs="1"`

Comment: I am littile confused on this.
where I need to add the minOccurs = "1" @KlausGütter

Comment: I can able to convert the above mentioned XSD to expected XML through the online converters like LiquidXML. I have tried with some other piece of code and still it showing the result "Current XML" mentioned in the ticket.
I have tried with minOccurs,Maxoccurs,<xs:anyAttribute/> but sill not getting the exact way to convert the xsd to xml

Comment: I am adding the  sample codes in ticket

Comment: `<xs:element name="Months" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>`

Comment: No. that will not work.
I found the root cause of Xml conversion issue. That is a bug in the package, the current version will not allow to evaluate 2nd level node elements to be evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the XmlSampleGenerator.dll

```
private bool GenerateElement(XmlSchemaElement e, bool root, InstanceGroup parentElem, XmlSchemaAny any) {
         XmlSchemaElement eGlobalDecl = e;
         bool flagCached = false;
         if (!e.RefName.IsEmpty) {
               eGlobalDecl = (XmlSchemaElement)schemaSet.GlobalElements[e.QualifiedName];
         }
         if (!eGlobalDecl.IsAbstract) {
               InstanceElement elem = (InstanceElement)elementTypesProcessed[eGlobalDecl];
               if (elem != null) {
                   Debug.Assert(!root);
                   if (any == null && e.MinOccurs > 0) { //If not generating for any or optional ref to cyclic global element
                       decimal occurs = e.MaxOccurs;
                       if (e.MaxOccurs >= maxThreshold) {
                           occurs = maxThreshold;
                       }
                       if (e.MinOccurs > occurs) {
                           occurs = e.MinOccurs;
                       }
                       elem = elem.Clone(occurs);
                       parentElem.AddChild(elem);
                       flagCached = true;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   elem = new InstanceElement(eGlobalDecl.QualifiedName);
               }
               if(root) {
                   instanceRoot = elem;
               }
               else {
                   if(!flagCached)
                   parentElem.AddChild(elem);
                   flagCached = false;
               }
               //Get minOccurs, maxOccurs alone from the current particle, everything else pick up from globalDecl
               if (any != null) { //Element from any
                   elem.Occurs = any.MaxOccurs >= maxThreshold ? maxThreshold : any.MaxOccurs;
                   elem.Occurs = any.MinOccurs > elem.Occurs ? any.MinOccurs : elem.Occurs;
               }
               else {
                   elem.Occurs = e.MaxOccurs >= maxThreshold ? maxThreshold : e.MaxOccurs;
                   elem.Occurs = e.MinOccurs > elem.Occurs ? e.MinOccurs : elem.Occurs;
               }
               elem.DefaultValue = eGlobalDecl.DefaultValue;
               elem.FixedValue = eGlobalDecl.FixedValue;
               elem.IsNillable = eGlobalDecl.IsNillable;
               if (eGlobalDecl.ElementSchemaType == AnyType) {
                   elem.ValueGenerator = XmlValueGenerator.AnyGenerator;
               }
               else {
                   XmlSchemaComplexType ct = eGlobalDecl.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;
                   if (ct != null) {
                       if(!elementTypesProcessed.ContainsKey(eGlobalDecl)) elementTypesProcessed.Add(eGlobalDecl, elem);
                       if (!ct.IsAbstract) {
                           elem.IsMixed = ct.IsMixed;
                           ProcessComplexType(ct, elem);
                       }
                       else { // Ct is abstract, need to generate instance elements with xsi:type
                           XmlSchemaComplexType dt = GetDerivedType(ct);
                           if (dt != null) {
                               elem.XsiType = dt.QualifiedName;
                               ProcessComplexType(dt, elem);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   else { //elementType is XmlSchemaSimpleType
                       elem.ValueGenerator = XmlValueGenerator.CreateGenerator(eGlobalDecl.ElementSchemaType.Datatype, listLength);
                   }
               }
               if (elem.ValueGenerator != null && elem.ValueGenerator.Prefix == null) {
                   elem.ValueGenerator.Prefix = elem.QualifiedName.Name;
               }
               return true;
         } // End of e.IsAbstract
         return false;
       }
```

It is working for me,Please check